# Submit form after progress bar submit animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, animation

I need your help.

I have some submit buttons with an animation, here is a working demo:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/KhDdXWYnj3kVxhiKaEFL
```

But now the submit don't works, just ask and play animation. not submit the form

```
<button type="submit" name="send_approve" onClick="return message1()" class="progress-button" data-style="rotate-back" data-perspective data-horizontal>Enviar </button>
```

this is the code for animation:

```
[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'button.progress-button' ) ).forEach( function( bttn ) {
            new ProgressButton( bttn, {
                callback : function( instance ) {
                    var progress = 0,
                        interval = setInterval( function() {
                            progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1 );
                            instance._setProgress( progress );

                            if( progress === 1 ) {
                                instance._stop(1);
                                clearInterval( interval );
                            }
                        }, 200 );
                }
            } );
        } );
```

Before to the animation I had this and works fine, but now I just want press button, animation and submit without confirm validation

```
    function message1() {

             var r = confirm("¿ Sure to submit ?");
            if (r == true) {
            return true;

                            }
    else    {
            alert('it didnt work');
            return false;
            }   
                    }
```

You know how can I do that ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: It would be useful if you would allow us to play with that button, by posting a "working" version of what you have now [here](http://plnkr.co/) and then share a link with us. Otherwise we can only guess how that animation works

Comment: @StefanBaiu sure, here it is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KhDdXWYnj3kVxhiKaEFL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first make sure you remove that `onclick` attribute if you don't want to prompt that question anymore.
Second, make sure your button, along with all the other fields, is wrapped inside a `form` tag, like this:

```
<form name="theForm" method="GET" action="http://www.google.ro/search">
    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="enter search keyword" />

    <button type="submit" <!-- rest of the attributes except for onclick -->>
         <!-- rest of the content, like those spans go here -->
    </button>
</form>
```

Third, in JS, after the progress is done just submit the form:

```
if ( progress === 1 ) {
    instance._stop(1);
    clearInterval( interval );

    document.forms["theForm"].submit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I made that before and reload the page because i have a   `action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?> "` but also have a validation `if (isset ($_POST['send_approve']))` and that don't works,I think is not recognized. Hope you can help me.

Comment: what is 'send_approve'? is that a checkbox you need to check before submit? anyway, the server expects a value for that, so you need to have an input with name="send_approve" and a value="whatever you need"; if you don't want to show it to your users, you can use an input of type="hidden", just put a value there for the server to receive

Comment: Is the submit button, but is fixed, after the progress bar button I simulate the clic `$( '#send_approve' ).click ();` and that press this `<input type="submit" name="send_approve" id="send_approve" style="display:none;"/>`Thanks for your help.